# Are not rules applied in succession?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, rule

I am trying this:

```
makeless[x_, y_] := {
  Imp[x, y] -> True,
  Imp[And[p___, x, q___], y] -> True
  }

myrules = {
   Imp[x_, True] -> True,
   And[p___, Imp[x_, y_], q___] :> 
      And[And @@ ({p} //. makeless[x, y]), Imp[x, y], And @@ ({q} //. makeless[x, y])]
   };
```

(need to implement intuitionistic implication).

I expect

```
Imp[a, True] && b //. myrules
```

to return `b`, but it just returns the same (i. e. `Imp[a, True] && b`).

Should not the first rule in the list, `Imp[x_, True] -> True` be applied first? It would then give `True && b` which would evaluate to `b`.

What am I doing wrong and how to do it right?

Comment: [`Trace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) lets you follow the internal evaluation process step by step. It's a great tool to debug this kind of situation.

Comment: In addition to what @Roman said: rules are applied in order, but only at a given level - the levels are traversed from the outside in for `ReplaceRepeated`, so the second rule is applied to the entire expression, before anything else is checked deeper down. To get traversal from the inside out, take a look at `Replace` with levelspec `All`, and probably using `FixedPoint` for the repeated application

Comment: @Roman I tried `Trace`, but could not find out anything: `{{myrules,{Imp[x_,True]->True,p___&&Imp[x_,y_]&&q___->p&&Imp[x,y]&&q}},Imp[a,True]&&b//. {Imp[x_,True]->True,p___&&Imp[x_,y_]&&q___->p&&Imp[x,y]&&q},Imp[a,True]&&b}`

Comment: @LukasLang Could you make it an answer? This seems to be what I need.

Comment: @LukasLang I am trying it on other expressions and became totally confused: in some cases `Replace[expr,myrules,1]` does more than `Replace[expr,myrules,All]`